# VHDL Conditionals (in if then) using "=" vs ":="

Tags: vhdl

I'm getting an error in my VHDL 1993 code  which I cannot solve in the following code line:

```
if (((cur_stap2 := IDLE) or (cur_stap2 := MDLE)) AND (txe_n = '0') AND (wr_n = '1')) then
```

VHDL compiler issues an error with this statement:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at mst_fifo_fsm.vhd(123) near text ":=";  expecting ")", or ","
```

IDLE, MDLE are states which are declared with this lines of code:

```
type states is (IDLE, MTRD, MDLE, MTWR);
signal current_state, next_statem, cur_stap1, cur_stap2, cur_stap3, cur_stap4 : states;
```

txe_n and wr_n are normal signals with type std_logic.

Can you please tell me what is the correct way of checking if these conditions are met?

Thank you in advance

using Intel Quartus 17.0

Comment: First, don't use variable assignment in a boolean expression. This isn't C, and assignment isn't an operator.

Comment: Vote close, as this question was caused a simple typographical error.

Comment: @JHBonarius Sorry, what do you mean with typographical error? And where?

Comment: The error is caused by using `:=` (variable assignment operator) instead of `=` (is equal comparison operator). That's a typo.

Comment: Looks to me like a common coding problem that many new users may have.   I am surprised it was closed.     Quoting the "shortest program" rules really only frustrates users.   This is particularly true when an experienced user readily sees the issue and can explain the error.

Comment: @JHBonarius   Not a typo.   A common misunderstanding.   I disagree with it being closed, but don't see a way to fix that.   This kind of behavior by stack overflow overlords (none of the ones listed there even have a VHDL tag) is demoralizing for both the people who ask the questions and those who provide relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses a ":=" where it needs an "=".  Your code corrected is:

```
if (((cur_stap2 = IDLE) or (cur_stap2 = MDLE)) AND (txe_n = '0') AND (wr_n = '1')) then
```

":=" is for variable assignment and initialization in declarations.  "=" is for comparison.

Note: Compilers do not have AI.   The way to read this error message (and any error message in general) is "Dear user, I found ":=" and I died.   I think the reason is ..."   Note sometimes the "..." is useful, sometimes it is not.  So in this case, it correctly told you, don't use ":=" here.